# How do you control MySQL timeouts from SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

What's the right way to control timeouts, from the client, when running against a MySQL database, using SQLAlchemy?  The `connect_timeout` URL parameter seems to be insufficient.

I'm more interested in what happens when the machine that the database is running on, e.g., disappears from the network unexpectedly.  I'm not worried about the queries themselves taking too long.

The following script does what you'd expect (i.e., time out after approximately one second) if *somehost* is unavailable **before** the `while` loop is ever reached.  But if *somehost* goes down **during** the `while` loop (e.g., try yanking out its network cable after the loop has started), then the timeout seems to take at least 18 seconds.  Is there some additional setting or parameter I'm missing?

It's not surprising that the `wait_timeout` session variable doesn't work, as I think that's a server-side variable.  But I threw it in there just to make sure.

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.exc import *
import time
import sys

engine = create_engine("mysql://user:password@somehost/test?connect_timeout=1")
try:
    engine.execute("set session wait_timeout = 1;")
    while True:
        t = time.time()
        print t
        engine.execute("show tables;")
except DBAPIError:
    pass
finally:
    print time.time() - t, "seconds to time out"
```

Comment: It sounds like there ought to be a network-level timeout associated with the socket that you use to connect to the db...

Comment: There is, for initiating the network connection, but once the connection is established it would appear there is less you can do.  This would appear to be, in part, due to how TCP is _supposed_ to work (e.g., be fairly tolerant of failures or long periods of idle communication, etc.)

Comment: wait_timeout defines how long the client has between commands before the mysql server decides to drop the connection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this isn't possible due to the way TCP works. if the other computer drops off the network, it will simply stop responding to incoming packets. the "18 seconds" you're seeing is something on your TCP stack timing out due to no response.

the only way you can get your desired behavior is to have the computer generate a "i'm dying" message immediately before it dies. which, if the death is unexpected, is completely impossible.

have you ever heard of hearbeats? these are packets that high-availability systems send to each other every second or less to let the other one know they still exist. if you want your application to know "immediately" that the server is gone, you first have to decide how long "immediate" is (1 second, 200 ms, etc.) and then designed a system (such as heartbeats) to detect when the other system is no longer there.

Comment: That's actually one of the things I was wondering; if the protocol between the MySQL client and server included some kind of periodic heartbeat (e.g., even while a long query was going on there would be a periodic heartbeat).

Comment: no, there is not. there is one between servers when using the clustered version, but not between the client and the server.

Comment: Accepting..  This basically jibes with what I just read in Effective TCP: http://home.netcom.com/~jsnader/etcptoc.html

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are reaching a totally different error, this is a dreaded "mysql has gone away" error, If I'm right the solution is to update to a newer mysqldb driver as the bug has been patches in the driver.

If for some reason you can't/won't update you should try the SA fix for this

```
db= create_engine('mysql://root@localhost/test', pool_recycle=True)
```

Comment: "mysql has gone away" results when the mysql server disconnects gracefully at the TCP level (i.e. FIN) but abnormally at the application level. so this will not assist in detecting a server crash because a crashed server sends no FINs.

Comment: pool_recycle takes an integer indicating the number of seconds before recycling a connection in the pool, not a boolean (maybe it did in 2009, no idea)

Answer (score 1):

Could this be a bug in the mysql/python connector?
https://bugs.launchpad.net/myconnpy/+bug/328998
which says the time out is hard-coded to 10 seconds.

To really see where the breakdown is, you could use a packet sniffer to checkout the conversation between the server and the client. wireshark + tcpdump works great for this kind of thing.