# Avoiding socket timeouts in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sockets, timeout, sqlalchemy, python-3.x

I'm new to SQLAlchemy, but I'm trying to use it to create and fill a database for a personal project.  I've set `pool_timeout` to 43200 (twelve hours), but I'm still getting socket timeouts.

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
            'postgresql+pg8000://gdwatson:pass@localhost/dbname',
            pool_timeout=43200)
db.tables.meta.drop_all(bind=engine)
db.tables.meta.create_all(bind=engine)

conn = engine.connect()
dataset = build_dataset()
conn.execute(db.tables.mytable.insert(),
             dataset)
conn.close()
```

I end up getting `socket.timeout: timed out` after a good deal of processing time, but probably under an hour and certainly under two.  It's actually three levels deep-- while handling the timeout exception another occurred, and then when handling that one yet another occurred.  (Perhaps this is the library retrying?)  The exception occurs in `conn.execute`, and I'm at a loss as to how to prevent it.

A search hasn't turned up anything informative.  I am using Python 3.1 and SQLAlchemy 0.6.1, for what it's worth.

Comment: I ended up slicing dataset into 1000-entry chunks and inserting it one chunk at a time.  That worked around the problem, even if it's a bit uglier.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is the recommended method, but you could periodically send a `SELECT 1` statement and ensure the connection isn't idle.

You could also look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209640/how-do-you-control-mysql-timeouts-from-sqlalchemy) for some guidance